# Можно ли зациклить данный код, который присваивает переменной определенные значения в зависимости от даты

Tags: python, циклы, datetime

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
if d.isoweekday() == 1:
    d_2 = '*** ['+d.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+mon_1+'\n'
elif d.isoweekday() == 2:
    d_2 = '*** ['+d.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+tue_1+'\n'
elif d.isoweekday() == 3:
    d_2 = '*** ['+d.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+wed_1+'\n'
elif d.isoweekday() == 4:
    d_2 = '*** ['+d.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+thu_1+'\n'
elif d.isoweekday() == 5:
    d_2 = '*** ['+d.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+fri_1+'\n'
elif d.isoweekday() == 6:
    d_2 = '*** ['+d.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+sat_1+'\n'
elif d.isoweekday() == 7:
    d_2 = '*** ['+tomorrow.strftime("%d.%m")+'] '+mon_2
```

Здесь, собственно, идет присваивание переменной определенного значения в зависимости от текущей даты(Понедельник - mon, и т.д.). Можно ли как-то зациклить данный отрывок кода?

Comment: Совет: используйте форматирование строки и избегайте повторения кода

Comment: Что хранится в переменных mon_1, tue_1  и т.д.? Возможно, вы изобрели уже имеющийся велосипед.

Answer (score 0):

Пример зацикливания кода (+ небольшой рефакторинг):

```
import datetime as DT
import time


PATTERN_STR = '*** [{:%d.%m}] {}\n'

while True:
    d = DT.datetime.now()
    weekday = d.isoweekday()

    if weekday == 1:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, mon_1)
    elif weekday == 2:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, tue_1)
    elif weekday == 3:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, wed_1)
    elif weekday == 4:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, thu_1)
    elif weekday == 5:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, fri_1)
    elif weekday == 6:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, sat_1)
    else:
        d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(tomorrow, mon_2)

    print(d_2)

    # Задержка на 5 минут
    time.sleep(5 * 60)
```

---

С большим рефакторингом:

- Используем словарь, чтобы избавиться от кучи `if`/`else`

Пример:

```
...

WEEKDAY_BY_STR = {
    1: mon_1,
    2: tue_1,
    3: wed_1,
    4: thu_1,
    5: fri_1,
    6: sat_1,
    7: mon_2,
}


while True:
    d = DT.datetime.now()
    weekday = d.isoweekday()

    # Для weekday == 7 нужна другая дата -- tomorrow
    if weekday == 7:
        d = tomorrow

    d_2 = PATTERN_STR.format(d, WEEKDAY_BY_STR[weekday])
    print(d_2)

    # Задержка на 5 минут
    time.sleep(5 * 60)
```